# jQuery post json как получить ответ с комментариями кода?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post

1.php

```
var arr = {"token":"123"};
  $.ajax({
    url: '2.js',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(arr),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    //async: false,
    success: function (r) {
      console.log('res');
        console.log(r);
    }
});
```

2.js

```
/*xxx*/{"result":"1000"}/*xxx*/
```

Как получить ответ не убирая **/*xxx*/** ?(без них все работает)

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) JSON не поддерживает комментарии. Поэтому правильный путь - вырезать комментарии на стороне сервера.

Comment: Наверное, стоит отдельно подчеркуть, что клиент в этом случае **должен** ломаться и это нормально.

Comment: @D-side Согласен. Однако иногда все-же приходится браузер ставить на костыли, например, если сервер "не наш"

Answer (score 0):

```
dataFilter: function(response) {
    return response.replace("/*xxx*/","").replace("/*xxx*/","");
},
```

Comment: Тогда уже хотя бы так: `dataFilter: function(response) { return response.replace(/\/\*.+?\*\//g, ""); }` Правда будет проблема, если комментарий окажется внутри строки, но это решается только полным синтаксическим разбором с удалением комментариев